# Wearable that will track sleep and heart rate

Tags: smart-device

I'd like to find a wearable that can help track my sleep and heart rate. I'm definitely not interested in device that *requires a subscription to use, or to collect/present some or all of my health data to me*.

I looked into Withings' devices and they look more or less like what I'm looking for - I'm going to try a Pulse HR but beyond that, I'd like some other suggestions.

Watch functionality is optional, but if it's not a watch it needs to be as small/un-intrusive as possible because I do also wear a watch.

Comment: The only way to know for sure it doesn't require subscriptions or collect data for the manufacturer is open source firmware and AFAIK nobody does that

Comment: I doubt there's a self-contained device with sufficient processing power to do this standalone - hence the entire net backend for such as Apple Watch.

Comment: Maybe the fitness watches from Garmin will interest you? I use a Vivoactive 4S which logs data to the watch itself and can be shown on graphs right on the watch. The data is also available to copy off the watch's USB storage. The app is optional after doing the initial setup, doesn't even need internet or a phone in range to work.

Comment: @Irsu85 I don't mind if they keep (some) data. I don't want a subscription.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm okay with them processing on their side. It's the subscription in order for _me_ to have access that drives me crazy.

Comment: Yeah Garmin might be pretty good for you then, no subscription needed at all and if you do use the app you get to see a longer history and better reports than the watch can show alone.

Answer (score 0):

Any Android Watch can use the app [Sleep as Android](https://sleep.urbandroid.org/more/download/).  I have been using it for years to track my sleep and for the smart wakeup feature.  Where it tries to wake (in the time band set) when you are not in deep sleep.  In the free mode, you can do  all the basic stuff.  But it has many bells and whistles you can pay for.

Now in 2023/2024, Samsung phones do a half decent job of sleep tracking as well.